# Are these equivalent conditions?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f$ satisfy
$$\int_{a}^{x^{\prime}}f(x)dx+\int_{x^{\prime}}^{b}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$$
for any $x^{\prime}\in[a,b]$. Is this condition sufficient to imply absolute convergence,
$$\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|dx<\infty?$$

Comment: @geetha290krm: can you please show me an example when this fails?

Comment: The answer depends on what exactly you mean by that equation. If you are assuming that $f$ is a  bounded Riemann intergable function on $[a,b]$ the the hypothsis and the conlcusion are both true.

Comment: @geetha290krm: and what if I do not assume that $f$ is bounded?